# ¿Cómo hacer para que Checkbox no realice la acción si no está marcado?

Tags: java, android

Esta es la función de mi `CheckBox`:

```
check_nomostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE)
                            .edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun", false).commit();
            }
        });
```

Lo que hace es que si marco el `CheckBox` guarda en `SharedPreference` que no se vuelva a mostrar esa `Activity`, pero mi problema viene que si lo marco y lo desmarco la acción ya queda activada, quiero que si lo desmarco no se realice la acción. La acción solo debería activarse si marco el `CheckBox` y luego pulso este botón:

```
    btn1_guia3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GuiaParte3.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Explicado de otra manera:

Ahora funciona así

Marco `CheckBox` y se activa esa función, pero si la desmarco ya queda activada.

Lo que yo quiero es:

Marco `CheckBox` pero no se activa hasta que haga clic en `btn1_guia3`, si desmarco el `CheckBox` y hago click en `btn1_guia3` que no se active esa función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    check_nomostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                    "SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                editor.putBoolean("enableFunction", true).commit();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("enableFunction", false).commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

---

```
        btn1_guia3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GuiaParte3.this.finish();
                boolean enableFunction = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE)
                       .getBoolean("enableFunction", false);
                if(enableFunction){
                    yourFunction();
                }
            }
        });
```

---

```
private void yourFunction(){
    //your code
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Sugerencia de @Curro:

```
check_nomostrar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
               "SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

       if(isChecked){
           editor.putBoolean("enableFunction", true).commit();
       } else {
           editor.putBoolean("enableFunction", false).commit();
       }
   }
```

}
);

Comment: Solo tienes que añadir la linea GuiaParte3.this.finish();. He editado la respuesta

Comment: La sugerencia de Curro no me ha funcionado, pero lo que me has comentado sí, gracias! Solucionado ^^

Answer (score 0):

Es mas sencillo que eso. Tienes un listener especifico para lo que buscas:

```
TuCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

       }
   }
);
```

Con el compruebas si esta ckequeado y entonces haces una accion, de lo contrario,sino esta chequeado haces otra o no haces nada.

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Pero mi problema es diferente, no quiero que realice ninguna acción hasta que no hago clic en `btn1_guia3` por lo tanto si hago marco el `CheckBox` no debería hacer ninguna acción hasta que no haga clic en `btn1_guia3`